# How can I fix Text problem of Before XML Codes

Tags: php, xml

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<urunler>
<product>
<urun_kodu>70650977</urun_kodu>
<urun_adi> 10 lu Led Işıklı Fotoğraf Mandalları</urun_adi>
<fiyat>22,00</fiyat>
<desi>0.10000000</desi>
</product>
</urunler>
```

This is my xml file. When i read a file, i can not read. When i delete first sentence &  first row of the XML file, it works.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("oku.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

print_r($xml);
```

This is my php codes. Its basic simplexml.

How can i ignore first row of XML File in the PHP.  Can you help me?

Comment: Isn't that just from your browser pretty printingthe XML? What if you use the "View Source" option?

Comment: How did you get the XML file? That looks like it was copied from a browser instead of requesting the source directly.

Comment: I took the xml file from the browser, and i Saved as .xml, and i work Local. The problem is that when i delete first row it works. Otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: You did it incorrectly then. Just delete that line from the file, it wouldn't normally / shouldn't be there.

Comment: I can not delete every time. The file is changing all nights. I should fix that problem. The xml file is there: toptangidiyor.com/toptangidiyor

Comment: Just checked, that link does not have that text at the top of it. Still looks like you're copy and pasting the browser rendered version of the XML which is incorrect.